# pgsql views good practice about REFRESH MATERIALIZED

Tags: sql, database, laravel, postgresql, view

I use 2 pgsql views. One to calculate user's score and one to rank users base on their score.
The trouble is that when I fetch all rows in the view, (around 15K) it takes few seconds to process.

So I created my view using : `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_views` instead of: `CREATE VIEW my_views` which dramatically improved the loading time.
The drawback of this is that the views are not reactive (but I need them top be).

So I thought I would put a cron in my Laravel app who will every 5 minutes  refresh my views `DB::statement('REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_views');`

I do not know if it's a good practice to do so, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the best place to ask this kind of question, since you're not asking for a solution to your problem, rather you're asking if the solution you've already come up with is of good enough quality, which is an opinionated matter. However...

Comment: Personally, I'd say its good practice. Why? Because it solves the problem you have in your particular software. I don't know how it will scale long-term, and I'm concerned about the energy (environmental) cost of running this every 5 minutes involving many thousands of records. But, if it works consistently in your current software, then I think you did it right. You might run into issues with your implementation later & need to refactor, but that's usually sussed out by... well... running into the later problems, not by over-designing early on. **Disclaimer**: Based on personal experience.

Comment: @Reed i ask the question to be sure that what i intent to do is safe and that it is not a terrible practice. I want to be sure that it won't destroy my app or something like that.
Regarding the  environment, it will run only about one month per year (i will shut down the cron after that)

Comment: Right. It seems like a safe way to do things, though I don't have experience creating VIEWs or experience with laravel. Just make sure you're using version control for your code & keeping your database backed up & you can recover from any harm, with hopefully a minimal amount of lost data.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of MV query it may be better to put a triggers on participating tables and do partial update on data change (for example, identity the users affected by data change and execute your query only for that users as `update ... from...`)

Comment: @astentx i will look up for triggers on participating tables, i did not expect this toi exist

Comment: I mean you can create your own, but development and maintenance effort should be considered: maybe it is better to do full refresh on time intervals than write, test and debug triggers with concurrent updates that will work the same time. It depends on the amount of data changed during some short interval (if 60% of target view will be updated every 2 minute it will be useless triggers) and the complexity of relationships in the view query.